# Difference between Autosar Conformance testing and Acceptance testing

Tags: testing, autosar

I am very new to Autosar and looking at what needs to be done to test a SUT/DUT (System/Device under test) confirm to Autosar specifications
I read the  Autosar conformance test specification (Part 1 to 4)
and they have a separate link on website that talks of Acceptance test
In fact there is no direct link on portal for conformance testing. Only doing a Google search lead to those documents hosted by Autosar.org. So i presume conformance testing is also relevant to device testers

Are Autosar Conformance testing and Acceptance the same ?
When is Conformance test done and when Acceptance test are done ?

Thanks